# Why can't I see my ranked border?

Tags: league-of-legends, teamfight-tactics

I play only team fight tactics, and I reached platinum rank past season. Now when set 2 arrived during game loading my profile don't have ranked border. It shows only my LOL honor border. The other players have their ranked borders on point. I didn't change border which I want to see in my profile setup. I can see there my platinum rank, and that I have chosen ranking loading border.

Comment: I think that the season ending on the 5th of Novembre still needs some days/weeks to deliver all the season rewards to all the different players. You'll also get a penguin sticker with your last TFT rank as its armor! Did you got that already ?

Comment: No, I did't get anything. Will I also recive LOL skin, for TFT rank?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you may be waiting few days/weeks after the end of the ranked season as G.Eiwell said. Moreover the season 9 ends 19th November. You will not receive Aatroxx victorious skin for being at least gold in TFT.

EDIT : 
Acoording to LoL support and RiotTyphon: https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038152893-What-League-Rewards-Will-I-Get-2019-End-of-Season

Ranked TFT ends 5th November and Rewards will begin going out, on November 20th.